# MySQL Call Stored Procedure along with an UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am pretty much convinced that this is not possible but again I wanted to see if there is a possibility.

I have an UPDATE statement and I want to call a SP for each row updated. Is it possible someway to include the SP call along with the UPDATE statement?

Using a temporary table or another select query seems like a solution here though.

Comment: Would a `TRIGGER` suffice?

Comment: *I have an UPDATE statement and I want to call a SP for each row updated.* Do you want to call SP for a row before its updating, during it, after it? does this SP execution may affect on the updating process (may alter new value, may eject update, etc.)?

Comment: The SP adds a log for the UPDATE. So ideally we need to call SP after the update but it is ok even if we call before update as whole thing happens inside a SP.

Comment: *The SP adds a log for the UPDATE.* Use AFTER UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Akina that will work but what I’m checking is to couple the update with the current SP. There are other ways of update which the new trigger will interfere with. I will +1 you though

Comment: SP can be neither called in a query of any type except separate `CALL` nor used as row source in a query.

Comment: *There are other ways of update which the new trigger will interfere with.* Nothing prevents the setting for some flag/variable before update and execute the action in a trigger only when this flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it directly.

Convert your stored procedure into a function and use the return and some user defined variables for the update.

you also can call the stored procedure in a function, and youse the return values.

Comment: I tried it but it gives syntax error.. This seems not allowed.

Comment: I got this working by giving the function call in the WHERE clause and this function returns 1 always which will always evaluate to true. It seems this is ok. Comments please?

Comment: very good, as you only told us vage description, i gave you a a descrition how to go abut it, mysql has some restrictions, but they are all explained in the manual,

Comment: i made this original query into an SP and now - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored procedure or trigger. Seems like that is impossible to do this. :( Do you happen to know any other tricks for this? :)

Answer (score 1):

> The SP adds a log for the UPDATE.

Use trigger. Like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_writelog
AFTER UPDATE
ON updated_table
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO log ( old_column_value, new_column_value, updated_at, updated_by     )
  VALUES          ( OLD.column_name,  NEW.column_name,  NOW(),      CURRENT_USER() );
```

If you want to log not successful updates but all update attempts (including failed) then use BEFORE UPDATE trigger for to write the log and AFTER UPDATE trigger for to update logged attempt row marking the attempt was successful.

---

> There are other ways of update which the new trigger will interfere with.

No problems.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_writelog
AFTER UPDATE
ON updated_table
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO log ( old_column_value, new_column_value, updated_at, updated_by     )
  SELECT            OLD.column_name,  NEW.column_name,  NOW(),      CURRENT_USER() 
  WHERE @flag_tr_au_writelog IS NOT NULL;
```

If you need the trigger to be executed for some update then you execute

```
SET @flag_tr_au_writelog:=0;
```

before the update (use any non-NULL value).

If not - do not set it.

If you have set it for previous update but do not need to fire trigger for current update then execute

```
SET @flag_tr_au_writelog:=NULL;
```

before current update.

The variable `@flag_tr_au_writelog` is local for a connection, so it does not affect on concurrent connections/applications, and you do not need to clear it before application exit.